# why spyder is showing syntax error for def problem1_2(8,9)?

Tags: python

I have given this problem to solve as i am new to python,i have to get the sum and product of these nos. but it always shows syntax error symbolising 8,can anyone please help me how to solve this syntax error,i am running spyder 3.8;

```
def problem1_2(8,9):
    pass # replace this pass (a do-nothing) statement with your code
    sum = 8+9            
    product = 8*9
    print(sum)
    print(product)
```

```
File "<ipython-input-18-7071f70c407f>", line 1
    def problem1_2(8,9):
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You cannot provide numbers as arguments

Comment: then how to write this code?

Comment: How do you see other programmers writing a function which takes two parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot provide `integers` as parameters. You can, however, use 2 variables (parameters) local to the function and assign 8, 9 as default.

Also, please don't use built in functions as variables.

```
def problem1_2(num1=8,num2=9):
    sum1 = num1+num2          
    product = num1+num2
    print(sum1)
    print(product)
```

Comment: @surajkumar Most welcome. Consider accepting and upvoting the answer :)